# Negate characters for email Regex

Tags: regex, typescript, angular, regex-negation

I am trying to write a basic regex to validate an email address. For this specific case I am trying to make sure the string inputted only includes letters, numbers,  "." and "@". Or in other words I am making sure it doesnt include characters like £&¬! etc.

I tried getting the NOT version of this [[:alnum:].@]+ so that it would highlight a character not in that set but I couldnt get it to work. I also tried characters not in [\W.@]+ (the . is meant to be escaped but stackoverflow is removing the \ from this post) but the \W is still picking up the . and @ symbols.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: It will be used in typescript/Angular2

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you're saying `\W` is picking up `.` and `@`? That just means you can't use `\W` then, right? I would think, if you want a string that only has letters, numbers, . and @, you would want `[\w.@]`, note the lower-case `w`, and don't do any negation. Sidenote, I'm pretty sure (not positive) that you don't need to escape `.` inside brackets

Comment: Is there a reason why `[\w.@]` or  `[a-zA-Z0-9.@]` does not meet your needs?

Comment: I should have been clearer in saying that I want characters that do not match [\w.@] or [a-zA-Z0-9.@] to be highlighted

Comment: Sounds like you can just use `[^\w@.]` to find bad characters.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: `[\W.@]+ (the . is meant to be escaped` - Put back ticks around it `[\W\.@]+` But, the dot `.` does not need to be escaped inside character classes.

Comment: But, what I would use is `(?:[^\w@.]|_)+` to find invalid chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ...

- ... match for positives (your regex plus anchors to make sure it matches the complete test string)
  ( `^[[:alnum:].@]+$` )
- ... match for negatives which means that at some point an illegal character occurs
  ( `[^[:alnum:].@]` )

... and check whether there has been a match. n the first case that means 'ok', in the second 'fail'.

Theer are regex dialects that do not support posix character classes, in this case replace `[:alnum:]` with `0-9a-zA-Z`.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples of regex patterns for email addresses out there.  Here is a very basic/naive one that allows only alphanumeric and periods (and a single @).  This one does not care if the domain part is in a valid format (i.e. things like "abc@gmail......com" would pass):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9.]+@[A-Za-z0-9.]+$
```